# Adding 398 rows gives index out of bound but adding 397 doesn't give a crash .NET Core

Tags: c#, epplus

I am trying to export a file to excel and my code wasn't working in .net core (it works perfectly in .net) so i dumbed it totally down to this and it seems something is going wrong with just inserting rows past 397 in .net Core.

```
            for (int i = 1; i <= 398; i++)
            {
                wsData.Cells[i, 1].Value = i;
                wsData.Cells[i, 2].Value = i;
            }
            package.Save();
```

Exception thrown: 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' in EPPlus.dll
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
            for (int i = 1; i <= 397; i++)
            {
                wsData.Cells[i, 1].Value = i;
                wsData.Cells[i, 2].Value = i;
            }
            package.Save();
```

Works

Using version 4.5.2.1

I imported the project and it crashes at this  if statement because of the match variable i think

[image: Error]

EPPlus\Packaging\DotNetZip\Zlib\Deflate.cs(1463)

Comment: The code you've shown in an image which purportedly is the point at which the error is raised doesn't resemble the code you've put in your question.

Comment: That code is located in EPPlus\Packaging\DotNetZip\Zlib\Deflate.cs(1463) of the EPPlus library. It gets called in package.Save()